# How is a string value used as a boolean

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, visual-studio, boolean

I was playing around with my code in VB.NET (Visual Studio IDE) when I realised that I could affect a boolean value into a string

The string consequently took the value "True" or "False"

I then tried using it as a boolean such as

```
If StringValueContainingTrueOrFalse then
    'Do Something
End if
```

This also worked and is giving the desired result. This made me realise how little I knew about how things worked in the background.

Is the word *True* in the string being detected and the IDE is smart enough to deal with it or does it simply try to convert the value to what it needs to be (so knowing that it needs a boolean value try to convert the string into one to do it's actions) ?

What is happening making this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a non Boolean expression is used in the IF statement, Vb.Net compiler will convert the expression to Boolean using [`Conversions.ToBoolean`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.conversions.toboolean%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Your code is equal to

```
If Conversions.ToBoolean(StringValueContainingTrueOrFalse) then
    'Do Something
End if
```

If your value could be converted to a Boolean, all is well. Otherwise exception will be thrown.

For example:

```
Sub Main
    Dim StringValueContainingTrueOrFalse as String = "True"

    IF StringValueContainingTrueOrFalse then
    Console.WriteLine("true")
    end if  
End Sub
```

Above program generates the following IL:

```
IL_0000:  ldstr       "True"
IL_0005:  stloc.0     // StringValueContainingTrueOrFalse
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     // StringValueContainingTrueOrFalse
IL_0007:  call        Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToBoolean
IL_000C:  brfalse.s   IL_0018
IL_000E:  ldstr       "true"
IL_0013:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0018:  ret
```

You can see the label IL_0007 shows the call to `Conversions.ToBoolean` method.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as it explains very well the "behind the scenes" I was wondering about. However, if you could add Option Strict to your answer as the others do I feel like it would be a better all around explanation. Thanks for the clarifications

Comment: @micbobo I'm not sure aware about the details of that option. To be honest I'm a c# developer. I'm sure future readers will definitely read our comments and other answers as well. I don't have to repeat it in my answer. Btw, I don't like adding content to my answer which I don't understand fully.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the IDE doing it, rather it's doing a runtime cast from one type to another.  If the string contains a value that can be cast to a boolean, you're fine.  If not, you'll get a runtime error.

I would recommend using `Option Strict On` to get compile time errors instead, so you don't unintentionally rely on runtime casting you're not aware of.  If you turn this option on, the code in your question won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

VB expects a Boolean in the If block so it automatically tries to cast whatever your expression is to a Boolean using implicit conversion.

The Boolean casting recognizes true/false strings and correctly parses them.

This is normally considered risky. try adding

```
Option Strict On
```

Also see the MSDN documentation for VB.Net If statement :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

> condition Required. Expression. Must evaluate to True or False, or to
>   a data type that is implicitly convertible to Boolean.

Comment: You can also use integer (0/1) and bit (0/1) values as well which cast correctly to boolean values.

Answer (score 1):

When a String is directly used in an `if` statment, it'll try to convert it to a Boolean so it can perform the evaluation.  "True" or "False" can be converted to Booleans but other values cannot.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
            Dim StringValueContainingTrueOrFalse As String = "True"
        If StringValueContainingTrueOrFalse Then
            Console.WriteLine(StringValueContainingTrueOrFalse)
        End If

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

[image]

So to answer your question as to what's happening, there is a "behind the scenes" conversion that is happening.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is a boolean value:
MyString.Contains("true")
as in:
if MyString.Contains("true") then